# Display short form of a string

Tags: c, string, short

I am a beginner in C programming. I recently tried solving a simple problem to find the short form of a string. I can't understand why we are using `*(ptr+i-1)` in the program. What if I use only `* (ptr+i)`. Can anyone please tell me how this works?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char sent[100];
    char *ptr;
    printf("Enter a sentence : ");
    gets(sent);

    char len=strlen(sent);
    printf("%c",*sent);
    ptr=&sent;
    for(int i=1; i<len; i++)
    {
        if(*(ptr+i-1) == ' ')
        {
            printf(" %c",*(ptr+i));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're looking for a space character one character before the index.  Marks the beginning of a new word.

Comment: This looks like C, not C++. In C++ you'd use `std::string`s rather than C-style arrays of `char`.

Comment: ".. what if i use only `* (ptr+i)` .." – that's the great thing, you can actually go ahead and try it.

Comment: The whole ditto code copied from [here](https://cod3addicts.wordpress.com/2012/01/14/c-program-to-make-abbreviation-of-a-string/).

Comment: The thing with `*(ptr+i-1)` is that it is how beginners write what seasoned C programmers would write as `ptr[i-1]`. Likewise `*(ptr+i)` is just `ptr[i]`.

Comment: @LinuXMan So OP is not "solving a simple problem?"

Comment: [Never use `gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gets/info).

Comment: @LinuXMan: it is alright (-ish) to ask about existing code. But asking "how does `a+b-1` works" is at the low end of "what's there to understand about?"

Comment: @LinuXMan Whts the issue bud?

Answer (score 2):

> "*I can't understand why we are using `*(ptr+i-1)` in the program. What if I use only `* (ptr+i)`. Can anyone please tell me how this works?*"

```
for(int i=1; i<len; i++)
{
    if(*(ptr+i-1) == ' ')
    {
        printf(" %c",*(ptr+i));
    }
}
```

`*(ptr+i-1)` is important as `i` is starting by/ initialized to `1` not `0` regarding reading the string from its first character, not the second.

With `*(ptr+i)` you would read from the second character of the string instead.

---

Side note:

`gets(sent);` -> Don´t use `gets()`, it is deprecated:

[Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: If  I started the i=0, what will be the case?

Comment: @Code_Ostrich Then it would be okay.

Comment: I tried with 0 but i am not getting the output. Only the first character is displaying.

Comment: @Code_Ostrich What do you want to get as output instead? A string? Then use `%s` instead.

Comment: No i tried the same edited as i=0 and if condition as if(*(ptr+i) == ' ')
        {
            printf(" %c",*(ptr+i));
        }

Comment: @Code_Ostrich Yes, but what do you want to have as output? A string?

Comment: Now i am only getting the first character as o/p. I need the first character of the words in the string i entered.

Comment: @Code_Ostrich What is your input? Any space before a word?

Comment: My input will be a word like computer science. I need the short form of this as 'C S'.

Comment: @Code_Ostrich Then you need to use `printf(" %c",*(ptr+(i+1)));` because the offset points now to the white space instead of the first character of the second word.

Comment: @Code_Ostrich `printf(" %c",*(ptr+i));` -> `printf(" %c",*(ptr+(i+1)));`

Comment: Thanks a Lot friend. Thanks for helping a noob

Comment: @Code_Ostrich It was a pleasure to help you. If this answer helped you with your problem, feel free to accept it. :-)

Comment: Sure dear friend.